# From where does the WCF Test Client get its configuration?

Tags: .net, wcf, visual-studio, wcftestclient

I fear I've just lost myself in the trees, but from where does the WCF Test Client pull its configuration?

**Background** In troubleshooting adding support for net.tcp to my WCF service, I've muddied the waters by making many different changes to the web.config and restarted through the process with a very simple service.

When I add a service in the WCF Test Client, there are references to binding names that don't exist in the config file in the root of the service but do in some of the other subfolders including ones hanging off obj\debug like CSAutoParameterize and TransformWebConfig that until now I didn't know existed.  Edit: These look to be names from earlier trials/experiments--not just pulled from thin air.

When I make changes in the root config (web.config as I'm hosting locally IIS7.5/Win7) those seem to have no impact.

Thanks and sorry for what is going probably have a pretty obvious answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This data is saved in your Documents folder under "Test Client Projects".